# 'e-columns' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Issue occurs in Run ng test

context.js:265 'e-columns' is not a known element:

1. If 'e-columns' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'e-columns' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

**app.component.html**

```html
  <mks-query>
    <e-columns>
      <e-column field="EmployeeID" label="Employee ID" type="number"></e-column>
      <e-column field="FirstName" label="First Name" type="string"></e-column>
      <e-column field="TitleOfCourtesy" label="Title Of Courtesy" type="boolean"></e-column>
    </e-columns>
  </mks-query>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  exports:[AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.componenet.spec.ts**

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
  
});
```

Comment: You need to import the module where`e-colomns` is declared in the imports array of the Tesbed configurations,  in your spec file

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions.

If you need to test integration with `e-column` you need to import module containing it.

```js
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [ 
    EColumnModule, // I'm guessing the module's name here
  ],
}).compileComponents();
```

If there is no need to have such integration tests then it would be preferable to include `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` into config. This way the `e-column` would be treated as generic `HTMLElement`.

```js
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to import `mks-query` in `app.module.ts`

when you use angular components, you have to import in your module